# Integration w/r to the counting measure on $X$ with $|X| > \aleph_0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set with $|X| > \aleph_0$ and $\mu\colon \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty]$ the counting measure. I want to prove that if $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ then

$$\int_X fd\mu = \sum_{x \in X} f(x) := \sup\left\lbrace \sum_{x \in A} f(x) \colon A \subseteq X, \ |A| < \infty \right\rbrace$$

I also want to know what happens if $f$ is not positive.

My attempt:

If $A \subseteq X$ and $|A| < \infty$ then 
$$\int_Xfd\mu \geq \int_A fd\mu = \sum_{x\in A} f(x) $$
then we can take supremum on $A$ and we obtain 
$$\int_X fd\mu \geq \sum_{x\in X}f(x)$$

For the other inequality take a positive simple function $f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i1_{A_i}$ with $(A_i)$ pairwise disjoint and $a_i > 0$.
If $|A_i| \leq \aleph_0$ for all $i$ and $A := \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ (the support of $f$) then 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in X} f(x)
& = \sum_{x\in A} f(x)\\
& = \sum_{x\in A} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}(x) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\sum_{x\in A}1_{A_i}(x) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(A_i) \\
& = \int_X fd\mu
\end{align*}

And if $\exists i$ such that $|A_i|> \aleph_0$ then support of $f$ is uncountable and $$\sum_{x\in X} f(x) = \infty  \Longrightarrow \int_X fd\mu \leq \sum_{x\in X} f(x) $$ 
So in general, for every simple positive function $f$  we have that $$ \int_X fd\mu \leq \sum_{x\in X} f(x)  $$

Now If $f$ is a general positive function there exists a sequence of simple positive functions $0\leq f_n \leq f$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ then $$\int_X f_nd\mu \leq \sum_{x\in X} f_n(x) \leq \sum_{x\in X} f(x)$$
If we take limit we get the inequality.

So I only want to know what happens when $f$ is not positive

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The standard trick is to define $\int_X f = \int_X f^+ - \int_X f^-$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are the positive and negative parts, respectively, subject to the condition where at most one of the two integrals takes on a value of $\infty$, otherwise it is undefined. (Often you will see it required that both are finite, but there is no harm in assuming that one of them is infinite as the algebra all works out.) This then drops you into the analysis you did above. The reason being that if one of them is finite, the sup is actually a maximum and there is no analysis to be done there.